# I want my <p> to expand on click. But I am not able to do it

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor

html code

```
<template name="Item">
    <li class="pI">
        <p class="bucket">
            <li>
                <span class= "titleBody">
                    <strong>{{{title}}}</strong>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="contentMain">
                {{{content}}}
            </li>
            {{>commentsTemp}}
            <a href="#">Click to read more</a>
        </p>
    </li>
</template>
```

Client Code

```
$('.pI').find('a[href="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.pI').find('.bucket').toggleClass('bucket big');
});
```

CSS code

```
.bucket{
    height: 50px;
}

.big{
    height: auto;
}
```

I found the client side code on stackoverflow but it is not producing the desired result.
Basically I want to hide the bottom portion of the bucket paragraph and it should show when the "click to read more" is clicked. I want to restrict the height to 50px on start but it should expand on click.

Comment: Where is element with class `wrapper`?

Comment: Just use two classes, bucket and bucket-big and replace the class instead of adding the big class. Or is the problem that your selector doesn't find the correct element?

Comment: sorry "wrapper" was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to `toggle` the 'bucket' class? I don't think so, as you are using it to find your element. In addition, I think that you can immediately grab your `.bucket` with `.closest()`:

```
$('.pI').on('click', 'a[href="#"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.bucket').toggleClass('big');
});
```

this will add `big` to `.bucket` on the first click and remove `big` from bucket on the second click.

**Note:**

Your html disrespects every rule and convention. Nested `<li>`'s that are not wrapped by a unordered or ordered list are not valid. Consider to structure your code differently:

html

```
<ul>
    <li class="pI">
        <p class="bucket">
            <span class= "titleBody"><strong>title</strong></span>
            <span class="contentMain">content</span>
            <span class="comments">comments</span>
        </p>
        <a href="#">Click to read more</a>
    </li>   
    <!-- more list items here -->
</ul>
```

js

```
$('.pI').on('click', 'a[href="#"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('big');
});
```

Use this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0dyjLetv/) to play around.

Comment: Given it's Meteor, this template is probably nested inside another one that opens and closes the (un)ordered list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
$('.pI').on('click', 'a[href="#"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('big');
});
```

```css
.bucket{
    height: 50px;
}

.big{
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="pI">
        <p class="bucket">
          <span class= "titleBody"><strong>title</strong></span>
          <span class="contentMain">content</span>
          <span class="comments">comments</span>
        </p>
        <a href="#">Click to read more</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The meteoric way of attacking this problem is to attach an event handler to the template itself. This is particularly important if your template is being repeated inside an `{{#each}}` as I suspect yours is.

```
Template.Item.events({
  'click a': function(ev){
     $(ev.target).parent('.bucket').toggleClass('big');
  }
});
```

`ev` is the event object. `ev.target` is the event's target, and `$(ev.target)` is the DOM node.

You could even attach the event to the whole paragraph to give your users something bigger to click on:

```
Template.Item.events({
  'click .bucket': function(ev){
     $(ev.target).toggleClass('big');
  }
});
```